# Enviar archivo a través de api en JS

Tags: javascript, api

Estoy intentando llamar a una api pero al pasarle el body, me da un error ya que uno de los parametros a pasar debe ser un archivo pdf pero no tengo claro como hacerlo. La documentación de la API dice: **Este método está preparado para recibir una petición de tipo multipart/form-data, en el que una parte
del contenido (los documentos asociados al contrato) se transportan en un array de bytes y otra parte
(los metadatos del contrato) se transportan en formato JSON**.
El Error que recibo desde la api, es que no se está enviado el archivo.
Adjunto una captura de Posman.

```
importClass( "XMLHttpRequest" );

var url = theRoot.varToString( "URL" );
var met = theRoot.varToString( "MET" );
var hea = theRoot.varToString( "HEA" );
var par = theRoot.varToString( "PAR" );
var bod = theRoot.varToString( "BOD" );

//El body sería: files=C:/Users/A/Vo/cacherun/127.0.0.1/1341.pdf&metadata={"company_id":"B1","producer_id":"74"}
```

// Donde files, seberia ser un archivo en formato indicado anterior mente.

```
var cer = theRoot.varToString( "CER" );
var key = theRoot.varToString( "KEY" );
var clv = theRoot.varToString( "CLV" );
var pre = theRoot.varToString( "PRE" );
var err = 0;

// Declaramos el objeto XMLHttpRequest a utilizar
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
if( "" !== cer )
{
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.setClientCertificate( cer, key, clv );
}

// Si tiene parametros, los agregamos a la URL
if( "" !== par )
{
    try
    {
        var oJson = JSON.parse( par );
        var params = [];        
        for ( var i in oJson )
        {           
            params.push( i + "=" + oJson[ i ] );            
        }
        url += "?" + params.join( "&" );
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert("El JSON de los parametros esta mal formateado, debe verificarlo");
        err = 1;
    }
}

// Continuamos
if( 0 === err)
{
    // Seteamos la conexion
    xhr.open( met, url, false );

    // Si tiene headers, los agregamos  
    if( "" !== hea )
    {
        try
        {           
            var oJson = JSON.parse( hea );      
            var params = [];        
            for (var i in oJson)
            {           
                xhr.setRequestHeader( i, oJson[ i ] );                      
            }       
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            alert( "El JSON de los headers esta mal formateado, debe verificarlo" );
            err = 1;
        }
    }
    
    //Continuamos
    if( 0 === err )
    {
        //Evaluamos si hay un pre-script para ejecutarlo
        if ( "" !== pre )
        {
            eval( pre );
        }
        
        //Enviamos la consulta      
        xhr.send( bod );
        
        //Esperamos a que responda
        while( 4 !== xhr.readyState ) 
        {
            xhr.processEvents();
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]